# script longo no IE

Tags: jquery-select2

Um cliente relatou que no IE dele esta apresentando uma mensagem que o script estava longo demais, causando um travamento.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').each(function () {
       $(this).select2({
           allowClear: true,
            dropdownAutoWidth: true
        });
    });
});
```

Meu código acima, alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: O problema é esse   $('select').each(function (), você realmente precisa varrer todos os 'selects' da pagina ? esse código vai percorrer TODOS os selects da pagina o que provávelmente causa a lentidao

Comment: Mas ele entra no select each apenas cinco vezes, pois são 5 select mesmo.

Comment: Fiz assim, acho que pode melhorar:
$('select').select2({
    allowClear: true,
    dropdownAutoWidth: true
});